# The variable is being used without being initialized C++

Tags: c++, variables, initialization, stack, execute

I have tried looking for an answer and fixing this myself but I have failed.
I'm attempting to create a program that executes a letter guessing game. Please be advised that this IS homework. However, I'm not looking for answers, I am looking for insight. After executing this program I'm getting the error "The variable 'solution' is being used without being initialized C++.

Any ideas?

```
    #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
    #include <stdio.h>
    #define MAXGUESSES 4
    void GuessItRules();
    int PlayOneGame(char);
    char GetTheLetter();
    int IsAWinner(char, char);
    void CompareTheLetters(char guess, char letter);



    int main()
    {
    //declare additional variables
    //declare FILE pointer
    FILE *inp;
    int numGames, i = 0;
    //letter from file
    char letter;
    //variable for the return of the PlayOneGame function
    int didYouWin;


    char solution;


    //display instructions
    GuessItRules();
    //connect to the file HINT: use fopen
    inp = fopen("letterinput.txt", "r");

    //get number of games to play
    printf("How many games? (1 to 5): ");
    scanf("%d", &numGames);

    //this for loop will allow the player to play more than one game
    //without recompiling
    for (i = 0; i < numGames; i++)
    {
        //get a letter from file - use fscanf
        fscanf(inp, "%c", &letter);
        //print the letter back onto the screen, just to test
        //printf("\nThe letter is %c\n", letter);

        //Play one game (Call PlayOneGame function)
        //remember the function has an int return type
        printf("Let's play game %d\n", i + 1);
        PlayOneGame(solution);
        //tell the player if they have won or lost (test the variable didYouWin)

      }

      //close file
    fclose(inp);
    return 0;
}




    char GetTheLetter()
    {
    char guess;
    printf("\nMake a guess (CAPITAL LETTERS ONLY):");
    scanf("%c", &guess);
    return guess;
    }

    void CompareTheLetters(char guess, char letter)
    {
    if (guess == letter)
    {
        printf("\nThe Letter and the guess are the same (%c)\n",guess);
    }
    else 
    if (guess < letter)
    {
        printf("The letter comes after your guess (%c)", guess);
    }
    else 
    if (guess > letter)
    {
        printf("The letter comes before your guess (%c)", guess);
    }

    }

    int IsAWinner(char guess, char letter)
    {
    if (guess == letter)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
        if (guess < letter)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else
            if (guess > letter)
            {
                return 0;
            }
    }

    int PlayOneGame(char solution)
    {
    int numGuesses = 0;
    //SHOULD BE INITIALZED TO 1
    int winOrLose = 1;
    // user guess

    char guess = 0;

    //char solution = 0;
    char letter = 0;


    //As long as the user  has not used up the maximum number
    //of guesses and has not guessed correctly 
    //the game will continue using this while loop
    while (numGuesses < MAXGUESSES && winOrLose == 1)
    {
        printf("Getting guess number %d\n", numGuesses+1);
        //function call to GetTheletter - returns to guess variable
        GetTheLetter();
        //function call to IsAWinner - returns to winOrLose variable (0 or 1)
        IsAWinner(guess, letter);
        //function call to CompareTheLetters - gives the user  a message
        CompareTheLetters(guess, letter);
        //update counter for number of guesses used
        numGuesses = numGuesses + 1;

    }

    return winOrLose;  //(0 or 1)

    }

    //add the other function definitions

    void GuessItRules()
    {
    printf("Welcome to the Letter Guessing Game\n");
    printf("\nFirst, you will enter the number of games you want 
    to play (1 - 5      games)\n");
    printf("For each game you will have 4 chances to guess each letter\n");
    printf("Let's begin:\n");
    }
```

Comment: Read the warning. It's pretty explicit. What is the `solution` variable supposed to do?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I added "char solution" to initialise the "PlayOneGame(Solution)". I've been following the error messages for some time and adding where it says I have an error. It was the only way I and my basic experience told me too. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happens to a declared, uninitialized variable in C? Does it have a value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597405/what-happens-to-a-declared-uninitialized-variable-in-c-does-it-have-a-value)

Answer (score 1):

You are receiving that warning because you declare `char solution` and then pass it by value to the function `PlayOneGame(char solution)` without ever initializing it.  Since you are passing it in this way, you are implying that you intend to use it as a constant (not a `const`... I mean that you are passing only the value, not a reference to it, so it's not really mutable...) within the function.  As it stands, you don't use it at all, but this is the case of the message.

Comment: Thank you for breaking down and helping me get to the issue. However, it was my understanding that I had to initialise solution with char solution to define  the solution in PlayOneGame(solution).

Comment: @TheJr your function uses pass-by-value, which means that the function receives a copy of the argument. To do what you describe requires to use *pass by reference* .

Comment: How would I do that, exactly? &Thevalue?

Comment: You could pass the address of `solution`.  The prototype would be `PlayOneGame(char *var)` and the call would be `PlayOneGame(&solution)`.  Do some reading on pointers.